# Installing Database Driver in Superset running on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-superset

How can I install Database Driver in Superset Running on Top of **Kubernetes**.
based on the documentation, the recommended way is to add the pip installation inside [docker requirement](https://superset.apache.org/docs/databases/dockeradddrivers), but on the scenario of Kubernetes, I really don't wanna helm delete everything and then reinstall drivers.

Can I simply `k8s exec inside Pods (superset & worker )` and pip install manually or I need to make changes inside requirement and do complete helm reinstall?

Comment: Personally, I tried this with Requirements by uninstalling and re-install and it didn't work, don't know why.

Comment: Same problem here. I am trying to install dependencies manually

Comment: any updates? How did it resolve?